# sound is not coming in my earphones but it is coming from my laptop speakers

Tags: 12.04

Sound is not coming from my earphones but when I unplug my earphone sound comes from my speakers. My laptop is Asus k55v and my Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you check the volume when the earphones were plugged in?

Comment: if you dont know the solution then please dont tell me this

Comment: sorry. i actually had the same problem and i did not realise at first that there were two volume levels, one for speakers and one for earphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your audio drivers using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: its not working sound is still not coming